# How do two constraints work together for defining position on an axis

Tags: ios, autolayout

I came across method of using two constraints that work in conjunction to define a view's position along an axis. For example, I've a view who's Y axis constraint is

```
View.centerY = 0.3 x centerY
```

i.e. relative to `centerY`. Now, if I add another constraint:

```
View.top ≥ top + 10
```

Now it'll work if the top space happens to be `≥ top + 10` and it won't make a difference on relatively large screen devices. But, and this is my question, why does it affect smaller screen devices? Won't two constraint conflict when `top + 10` tries to push view downwards? Following screenshots shows the difference for iPhone 4s:

**Without ≥ top + 10**

[image]

**With ≥ top + 10**

[image]

Comment: sorry for misplacing the images

Comment: What is your question here? Do you want to know how or why this is working? I'm not sure which part you don't understand

Comment: @jrturton my question is how it's working. If top constraint is pushing view downwards, then how come it's not conflicting with centerY constraint.

Comment: It probably is, and it's probably telling you all about it in the console.

Comment: It won't, unless phone is rotated. Then it spits out warnings about constraints. BUT, if they'd be conflicting, why wouldn't IB warns about them?

Comment: Okay, I get it, they're conflicting on iPhone 4s and I didn't get warnings in IB cause my VC's size happens to be set to iPhone 7. I was wondering if there're any use case for using combination of constraints for defining a single axis or height/width.

Answer (score 0):

iphone 4s device size 320x480

This is happening due to this reason

1. first constraint 0.3 x centerY

centerY = 480/2 = 240

solve this 0.3 * 240 = 72

so view centerY = 72

2. view.top >= superview.top + 10
   [image: Iphone 7 view[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPHcq.png)
   solve this 
   superview.top = 0

so view y = 0+10 = 10 (y will be always greater or equal to 10)

You can check in attached image that i have set same constraint as you and views position changing both time, however my multiplier is 0.5 because in multiplier 0.3 both constraint will conflict each other.

Comment: But adding second one affects view's position. Also, view's centerY is equals to 72, not Y.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I was curious how come constraints aren't conflicting. As @jrturton commented they're and so I found the reason.